# Prove that the assertion is false if the positivity hypothesis is omitted

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need help with the Prove that the assertion is false if the positivity hypothesis is omitted part of this question please.

If $b_j>0$ for every $j$ and if $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}b_j$ converges then prove that $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)^2$ converges. Prove that the assertion is false if the positivity hypothesis is omitted. How about the third powers?

Since we are given that $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}b_j$ converges, we know by the Zero Test (Proposition 3.10 in the textbook) that the $b_j$ terms tend to zero as $j \rightarrow \infty$. As the terms tend to zero, the sequence of partial sums increase less and less with each succeeding term, ultimately converging to a finite value as $j \rightarrow \infty$.  Given the series $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)^2$, we expect that the $(b_j)^2$ terms will tend to zero even more quickly.  Therefore, we expect that the terms in the sequence of partial sums for the latter series will increase even more slowly, thus converging to a finite value more quickly, as well. \

I still need to prove that the assertion is false if the positivity hypothesis is omitted \

Given another series $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)^3$ having $b_j > 0$ for every $j$, we see that, since $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}b_j$ converges, this newest series will also converge for the same reason that $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)^2$ will converge --- because the sequence of partial sums approach a finite value as the new values added in each partial sum term decrease as $j \rightarrow \infty$. \

Answer (score 2):

If $b_j=\frac{(-1)^j}{\sqrt{j}}$, then $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}b_j$ converges, but $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}b_j^2=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j}$ diverges.

An counterexample for cubes is a bit trickier, especially if you want the $b_j$ to be real. I suggest trying to adapt the squares example by using third roots of unity in the numerator (note that $\pm 1$ are the square roots of unity).

Comment: Thanks for the help. If the positivity hypothesis holds on the cube power would it converge?

Comment: Yes, if $a_j>0$ and $\sum_{j}a_j<\infty$, then $\sum_ja_j^p$ converges for any $p>1$.

Answer (score 1):

TO-DO: Find a sequence $(b_j)_{j=1}$ so that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j$ converges but $\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j^2$ doesn't.

Idea: The harmonic series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}$ is divergent.

Set $b_j:=(-1)^j\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}$ . By Leibniz's test $\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^j\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}$ is convergent since $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}})_{j=1}$ is a null sequence.

Now we get $b_j^2=\frac{1}{j}$, which leads to $\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}$ - the harmonic series. Meaning the new series doesn't converge.